# Colunas em porcentagem não ficando alinhadas

Tags: html5, css3

estou usando em meu site 3 colunas(sections) cada uma com 33,33% de width e com margin-left e right de 10px para as 3. Só que a última coluna está caindo para baixo. Por elas estarem com width em %, não deveriam se ajustar ao tamanho do meu container ao invés de cair?

```
<main>
        <article>
            <section class="bg-col col-sm-4">
                <h2>Empresa</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <div class="more"><a href="empresa.php">Saiba Mais</a></div>
            </section>

            <section class="bg-col col-sm-4">
                <h2>Serviços</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <div class="more"><a href="servicos.php">Saiba Mais</a></div>
            </section>

            <section class="bg-col col-sm-4">
                <h2>Contatos</h2>
                <p>Tel: (xx) xxxx-xxxx</p>
                <p>E-mail: email@email.com.br</p>
                <div class="more"><a href="contatos.php">Saiba Mais</a></div>
            </section>
        </article>
    </main>
```

Comment: Por favor inclua o HTML na pergunta. De qualquer maneira, é o comportamento esperado: 99% de largura mais as margens ultrapassam o espaço disponível.

Comment: @bfavaretto como eu poderia resolver? o html foi incluido.

Comment: @Lucas Se minha resposta atende a sua necessidade, por favor marcar como aceita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue a solução no **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LguHE/6/)**

Eu simplemente defini largura de 30% para as section, e na section do meio dei uma margin de 5% pra esquerda e para direita, somando assim: 30% + 5% + 30% + 5% + 30% = 100%.
Onde, 30% corresponde ao espaço que a section ocupa, e 5% corresponde ao espaço entre as `section`.

```
article section                  { width: 30%; float:left; }
article section:nth-child(2)     { margin: 0 5%; }
```

**RESPONSIVIDADE:**
Quando se usa porcentagem, tudo se torna relativo, portanto se você quer alinhar lateralmente 3 Divs, deve-se levar em consideração TUDO que possa aumentar suas dimensões laterais, como:
- Border *(right e left)*
- Padding *(right e left)*
- Margin *(right e left)*
- Width *(principalmente a largura da própria div)*

A partir daí, deve-se pensar da seguinte forma.
Se quero uma div que ocupe 100% da largura disponível, tendo 5% de padding tanto na direta como na esquerda, deve-se aplicar as seguintes regras CSS:

```
.classe-da-div{
  width: 90%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%; 
/* 
    90% + 5% padding-left + 5% de padding-right = 100% 
*/
}
```

**RESPONSIVIDADE COM BORDAS**

Se quiser aplicar responsividade em blocos usando bordas, basta aplicar a propriedade `box-sizing: border-box` dessa forma a largura do bloco passa a ser automaticamente a soma do conteúdo com a borda e o padding, veja o exemplo:

```
.classe-da-div{
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 30%; /* Dentro desses 30% já estão calculadas as bordas e os paddings abaixo */
padding: 5%;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.classe-da-div:nth-child(2){
margin: 0 5%; /* Margem pra direita e pra esquerda da div do meio */
}
```

Seguindo esse raciocínio você pode montar um bloco com 3 divs alinhadas lateralmente, basta somar em porcentagem a largura das divs e dividir o que sobrar para as margens.

Veja esse **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LguHE/6/)** que eu fiz, ira te ajudar.

Comment: Teria como demonstrar o fiddle com border?

Comment: Neste caso deve ser adicionada a propriedade `box-sizing: border-box` ... a partir dessa regra, a box passa a contar o `width`o `padding`e o `border`como conteúdo total da box ... veja no [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LguHE/5/)

Comment: É, aí já não fica muito estável se quiser margem menor. De qq forma, grato.

Comment: Não fica? Claro q fica estável!
Suponhamos uma margem minúscula agora. Veja aqui http://jsfiddle.net/LguHE/6/  
Se preferir mova a divisória da janela resultado, pra ver o comportamento das DIVs

Comment: Ou pode ter a margem ainda menor como nesse **[exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/LguHE/6/)**, menor que isso? melhor nem ter margem!

Comment: Menor já melhorou, o que vai dar sempre trabalho, é acertar os múltiplos pra bater, e torcer pro browser arredondar certo o cálculo. Mas em vista dos limites do CSS, acho interessante a saída.

Comment: Não existe "torcer pro browser arredondar certo o cálculo", se você der os valores exatos ... se você tem 3 divs com 30% de largura cada (Já incluindo bordas e paddings, não importa o valor), faltam 10% pra completar os 100% do espaço, basta dividir os 10% por 2(Quantidade de espaços entre as 3 divs), obviamente fica 5% entre a primeira e segunda div, e mais 5% entre a segunda e a terceira. SIMPLES!

Comment: O problema é que não se trata de dividir 100% por várias colunas, mas se trata de somar várias coisas pra tentar chegar num 100% exato. Neste caso você corre o risco de acúmulo de erro de arredondamento (que é improvável, mas não impossível). Se trata de uma questão matemática, que como você disse, é SIMPLES.

Comment: Se pra você isso complica, vou te dar uma solução bem mais prática, procure estudar ***Flexbox***, vai se bater um pouco, mas é uma super ajuda na construção de pequenos templates

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que as larguras são relativas ao container. Esse 1% que está sobrando não está sendo suficiente para acomodar os 60px das margens.

A solução mais simples (mas que não funciona no IE9 e anteriores) é usar as propriedades de colunas do CSS3:

```
article {
    /* 3 colunas, 10px entre elas */
    -webkit-column-count: 3; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
       -moz-column-count: 3; 
       -moz-column-gap: 10px;
            column-count: 3; 
            column-gap: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LguHE/

Comment: Estas propriedades funcionam com qualquer tipo de elemento, ou só `article`?

Comment: Com qualquer elemento (talvez exista a restrição que ele seja um bloco).